# Get username info from active connection in Mapbasic

Tags: sql, sql-server, mapbasic, connection

I'm trying to retrieve information on username from active connection (SQL Server Express) in MapInfo 11.5 32bit. First I tried using **Server_ConnectInfo( ConnectionNo, SRV_CONNECT_INFO_SQL_USER_ID  )** which should return "*String result, returning the name of the SQL user ID.*" (by MapBasic Reference), but it returns "dbo" (my DB schema). Then I tried ***Server_GetODBCHConn()*** function. In MapBasic Reference this example stands:

```
'********************************************************************
'* Find the identity of the Connected database
DECLARE FUNCTION SQLGetInfo LIB "ODBC32.DLL" (BYVAL odbchdbc AS INTEGER, 
BYVAL infoflag AS INTEGER, val AS STRING, 
BYVAL len AS INTEGER, outlen AS INTEGER) AS INTEGER

Dim rc, outlen, hdbc, odbchdbc AS INTEGER
Dim DBName AS STRING

' Connect to a database
hdbc = Server_Connect("ODBC", "DLG=1")
odbchdbc = Server_GetodbcHConn(hdbc) ' get ODBC connection handle

' Get database name from ODBC
DBName = STRING$(33, "0") ' Initialize output buffer
rc = SQLGetInfo(odbchdbc, 17 , DBName, 40, outlen) ' get ODBC Database Name

' Display results (database name)
if rc <> 0 THEN
Note "SQLGetInfo Error rc=" + rc + ", outlen=" + outlen
    else
Note "Connected to Database: " + DBName
    end if

'********************************************************************
```

According to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetinfo-function syntax for SQLGetInfo is:

SQLRETURN SQLGetInfo(
      SQLHDBC         ConnectionHandle,
      SQLUSMALLINT    InfoType,
      SQLPOINTER      InfoValuePtr,
      SQLSMALLINT     BufferLength,
      SQLSMALLINT *   StringLengthPtr);

So, in line ***rc = SQLGetInfo(odbchdbc, 17 , DBName, 40, outlen)*** parameter "17" represents type of information we are requiring, but I can't find out what number represents username (*SQL_USER_NAME* stands as one of possible InfoType values, but no number is linked to this function). I have tried every number 1-60 but none of them returned username.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is off-topic. My problem is specifically linked to MapBasic. SQL can accept (is accepting)  InputType by its  name (eg. SQL_USER_NAME), however this is not the case in MapBasic, it requires specific ID (which I cant find anywhere).

Comment: It is clearly on-topic. Iant just don't know what he is doing.

Comment: I think this is OK result. Actually "dbo" string returned here is not a schema - it is a user that has implied permissions to perform all activities in the database (that is you logged in probably as "sa" or another user which has all permisions on that database). Try to create another user which has typical user rights and test it again.

Comment: @ sys49152. You are right! For all others I'm getting their usernames correctly, and mine is "dbo". Thank you